# Compress specific files in grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, nodes, grunt-contrib-compress

I am trying to compress few files in a folder and avoid files that are not required,

Structure:

```
    MainFolder-
    File1
    File2
    File3
    SubFolder1WithFilesInside
    SubFolder2WithFilesInside
    FolderToStoreZip
```

So I create an array

```
filesToPutInZip = [ 'MainFolder/File1', 'MainFolder/File2', 'MainFolder/SubFolder1WithFilesInside/**']
```

and called grunt compress

```
    compress:{
        main: {
            options:{
                archive: './FolderToStoreZip/final.zip',
                mode: 'zip'
            }
            src: filesToPutInZip
        }
    }
```

It gives me a zip file with MainFolder inside it.

So I also tried with cwd

```
    compress:{
        main: {
            options:{
                archive: './FolderToStoreZip/final.zip',
                mode: 'zip'
            }
            cwd: 'MainFolder/'
            src: filesToPutInZip
        }
    }
```

but it gives me an empty zip file.

And if I try to src `MainFolder/**` it will take all the files and folder